# How to add ColumnHeaders in datagrid with combobox?

Tags: vb.net

As said on the title, I need help with creating columnHeaders programmatically, and same goes to rows. I want a dynamic datagrid, with comboboxes on every item and all the columnHeaders based on 2 tables, one for the columns, and the other one for the rows.

Example

```
    Dim cmbHeaderCell1 As New ComboBox
    cmbHeaderCell1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    cmbHeaderCell1.Visible = True
    cmbHeaderCell1.Items.Clear()
    cmbHeaderCell1.Items.Add("India")
    cmbHeaderCell1.Items.Add("China")
    DGrdVLoadStb.Columns(1).Width = cmbHeaderCell1.Width

    'Dim X As Integer = DGrdVLoadStb.GetCellDisplayRectangle(1, -1, False).Location.X
    'Dim Y As Integer = DGrdVLoadStb.GetCellDisplayRectangle(1, -1, True).Location.Y
    cmbHeaderCell1.Location = New Point(datagridview1.Columns(0).Width + 2, 2)
    cmbHeaderCell1.Size = DGrdVLoadStb.Columns(1).HeaderCell.Size
    cmbHeaderCellStressRate.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    DGrdVLoadStb.Controls.Add(cmbHeaderCell1)
    cmbHeaderCell1.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried? and I think you forgot to attach your example.

Comment: You're sure about that! I'm so sorry. I'll update the question as soon as possible. But still could not figure out a way to put the "rowheader"(sort of speaking) to have a combobox, for example, instead of having that * symbol or > I would like to have a combobox that requires a project to be inserted.

Comment: If you want to have controls where the header usually is, things will get a bit tricky, your best bet would be to see if someone has made a control what you want to do, the best find I had was this: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/69eb64a8-fa93-4f99-b48e-5666287edc3b/dropdowncombobox-column-header-cell?forum=winformsdatacontrols).

Comment: I'll work something out based on that c# snippet. I'll keep everyone updated once I figure out a way to do so.